# Trigger toolkit not finding device

Tags: android, trigger.io

I have my Samsung Note 3 plugged into USB on my Mac and in Developer Options on the device I have enabled USB debugging. However, when I build for Android in Forge my device is not found. I entered 'device' without the quotes in config>tools section of the the toolkit but it is never found and default to the slow ass emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify the full device id in order to have the toolkit find mine. On my Nexus 4, it was the 16 char serial number located in Settings -> Status.

I also downloaded the [Google USB drivers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) and used Device Manager to browse for and install my Nexus 4's driver.

Your driver and others can be found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers